# Separation of variables in spherical coordinates issues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, spherical-coordinates

I am trying to follow this derivation of the solution of the spherical lapace equation. This is probably very simple but where did $-m^2$ on the bottom of page one?

[[image: Spherical]

Additionaly, what is happening between the bottom two lines. I know it says diff wrt r or $\theta$ but it doesnt look like the derivative has been taken.
[image: Spherical 2]

http://www.physics.usu.edu/Wheeler/EM3600/Notes11SeparationOfVariablesSpherical.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y(\varphi)=\frac{1}{\Phi}\frac{d^2\Phi}{d\varphi^2}$, then you effectively have an equation $dy/d\varphi = 0$, the solution is $y=\mathrm{const}=C$. However, if $C>0$, then the solution of equation
$$
\frac{d^2\Phi}{d\varphi^2}=C\Phi >0,\qquad \Phi = C_1e^{\varphi \sqrt C}+C_2e^{-\varphi \sqrt C}
$$
is non-periodic. However, we know that $\varphi$ is a cyclic variable, so $\Phi(\varphi)=\Phi(\varphi+2\pi)$. It means that $C\le0$. One of the way how to highlight it is to choose a constant that cannot be positive like $-m^2$.

In your second question, again let's denote functions to easily see what's going on:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(r) &= \frac{1}{R} \frac{d}{d r}\left(r^{2} \frac{d R}{d r}\right) \\
g(\theta) &=\frac{1}{\Theta} \frac{1}{\sin \theta} \frac{d}{d \theta}\left(\sin \theta \frac{d \Theta}{d \theta}\right)-\frac{m^{2}}{\sin ^{2} \theta} 
\end{aligned}
$$
You have an equation $f(r)+g(\theta)=0$, then you differentiate it by $r$, you will get $f'(r)=0$, the solution of this equation is $f(r)=\mathrm{const}=C_f$, by analogy the solution of $g'(\theta)=0$ is $g(\theta)=\mathrm{const}=C_g$. However, if you put those to the initial formula, you will get $C_f+C_g=0$, so clearly those constants are not independent. If you take $C_f=a$, then $C_g=-a$.